# How would you write $\frac{\partial m_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial H_j}{\partial x_i}m_j$ in vector notation?

Tags: vector-analysis, index-notation

The original paper uses Einstein summation notation as in the question title and I'm trying to write it using vector product notation. $\mathbf{m}$, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are all 3-component vectors.

My attempt is:

$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{m}}{\partial\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{m} \cdot \nabla\mathbf{H}$$

---

Is this correct? If it is, what does a dot product with the gradient of a vector look like, given that is a tensor?

Comment: Your equation makes no sense: $j$ is contracted only on the RHS.

Comment: @J.G. I had a feeling that might also have been the issue. The paper makes similar mistakes in a few other areas but in this instance I genuinely couldn't figure out any alternative meaning it should have.

Comment: I can only diagnose the typo if you link to the paper, so I can tell whether e.g. $H$ should be a scalar instead.

Comment: The paper is https://journals-aps-org.ezphost.dur.ac.uk/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.30.230 if you have access. My only thought is that maybe in this instance Einstein summation notation isn't used?

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: @J.G. No problem! It was a bit of a shot in the dark!